# About a step in the proof of Doob's $L^{p}$-maximal inequality

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

We had the above mentioned theorem in class recently.

> Assume that $(X_n)$ is a nonnegative submartingale. Then for all $n \in \mathrm{N}$ and all $p \ge 2$ 
>   $$
> \| \max_{k \le n}X_k \|_p \, \le \,  \frac{p}{p-1} \|X_n\|_p 
> $$

In the middle of the proof there is one step I can't follow. We introduced a stopping time $\tau$ given by

$$
\tau = \inf \{n :  X_n \ge K \}
$$

for $K \le \infty$ and then deduced

$$
\mathrm{E} \left[  \max_{k \le n}\left( X_{\tau \land k } \right)^p  \right] \le \mathrm E \left[  \max_{k \le n-1} \left( X_{\tau \land k } \right) ^p  \right] + \mathrm E \left[ \left( X_n \right)^p \right] \le K^p + \mathrm E \left[ \left( X_n \right)^p \right] .$$

I could see that this is true for example for a Brownian motion but why does this also hold in discrete time. Any help is appreciated very much.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply. I guess I get what you mean:
$$
U = \max \left\{ (X_{\tau \land 1})^{p}, (X_{\tau \land 2})^{p}, ... ,(X_{\tau \land n-1})^{p}  \right\} 
$$ and 

$$
V = (X_{\tau \land n})^{p} 
$$

and 

$$
\max \left\{ (X_{\tau \land 1})^{p}, (X_{\tau \land 2})^{p}, ... ,(X_{\tau \land n-1})^{p}  \right\} \le K^{p}
$$
 because we consider the process stopped by stopping time $\tau = \inf \{n :  X_{n} \ge K \}$.

My question about this the following: Why are we sure that the stopped process takes the exact value $K$ and not something greater than $K$?

Comment: In other words: As we do not have a process with continuous trajectories what if it jumps from a value less than $K$ to a value greater than $K$ - where the stopping time kicks in and fixes it at the last value taken...

Comment: Thanks for your carefully worded and perfectly valid objections to my first comment, which was way off base... It happens that the final result holds but I cannot fathom how the intermediary steps you reproduce in your question can help proving it (actually the wrong reasoning in my now deleted comment may be what the authors have in mind). See my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume without loss of generality that $p=1$ and consider $M_n=\max\limits_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}X_{\tau\wedge k}$, then $$M_n=M_n\mathbf 1_{\tau\geqslant n+1}+\sum_{k=1}^nX_k\mathbf 1_{\tau =k}$$

- On the event $\{\tau\geqslant n+1\}$, $X_{\tau\wedge k}=X_k<K$ for every $1\leqslant k\leqslant n$ hence $$M_n<K$$
- For each $1\leqslant k\leqslant n$, the event $\{\tau=k\}$ belongs to the sigma-algebra $\sigma(X_\ell; 1\leqslant \ell\leqslant k)$ and the process $X$ is a submartingale hence $$E(X_k\mathbf 1_{\tau =k})\leqslant E(X_n\mathbf 1_{\tau =k})$$

Summing these yields $$E(M_n)\leqslant KP(\tau\geqslant n+1)+E(X_n\mathbf 1_{\tau\leqslant n})\leqslant K+E(X_n)$$

Comment: I haven't gone through the details of your answer so you might have a simple explanation, but to me assuming $p=1$ seems counterproductive - Doob's max inequality is certainly not true in this case.

Comment: @Jason Except we are not proving Doob's inequality here, only an auxiliary result useful to prove Doob's inequality. And for the auxiliary result, $p=1$ or $p>1$ makes no difference.

Comment: @Didier Thank you very much for your great effort! Though I have not gone through the details yet this seems to be exactly what I have been asking for...Regarding your first comment (the one deleted by now) it was obvious to me that in my post I had not made my point clear enough. So it was easy for me to carefully word my following comment especially as I have greatest appreciation for irreplaceable contribution to this community here.

Comment: Why unaccept this?

Answer (score 1):

So meanwhile I tried to write everything together. I am very thankful for feedback.

Assume $(X_{n})$ a nonnegative submartingale, $\tau = \inf \{n :  X_n \ge K \}$ for $K \le \infty$ a stopping time and $p \ge 2$. We want to show
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E} \left[  \max_{1 \le k \le n}\left( X_{T \land k } \right)^p  \right] \le K^p + \mathbb{E} \left[ \left( X_n \right)^p \right] .
\end{align*}
Without loss of generality we can assume $p = 1$. So we will show that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E} \left[  \max_{1 \le k \le n}\left( X_{T \land k } \right)  \right] \le K + \mathbb{E} \left[  X_n  \right] 
\end{align*}
holds. We have
\begin{align}\label{eq3}
\max_{1 \le k \le n}\left( X_{T \land k } \right) = \max_{1 \le k \le n}\left( X_{T \land k } \right) \cdot 1_{\{T \ge n+1 \}}  + \max_{1 \le k \le n}\left( X_{T \land k } \right) \cdot 1_{\{T \le n \}} .
\end{align}
We take a closer look at the first summand of (\ref{eq3}). As we have for every $k$ with $1 \le k \le n$ 
\begin{align*}
 X_{T \land k } \cdot 1_{\{T \ge n+1 \}} &= X_{k} \cdot 1_{\{T \ge n+1 \}} < K \cdot 1_{\{T \ge n+1 \}}
\end{align*}
we also have for the maximum
\begin{align}
\max_{1 \le k \le n}\left( X_{T \land k } \right) \cdot 1_{\{T \ge n + 1\}} < K \cdot 1_{\{T \ge n + 1\}} .
\end{align}
Now we consider the second summand of (\ref{eq3}). We have
\begin{align*}
\max_{1 \le k \le n}\left( X_{T \land k } \right) \cdot 1_{\{T \le n \}} &= \max_{1 \le k \le n}\left( X_{T \land k } \right) \cdot \sum_{l = 1}^{n} 1_{\{T = l \}}   \\
&= \sum_{l = 1}^{n} \max_{1 \le k \le n}\left( X_{T \land k } \right) \cdot 1_{\{T = l\}} \\
&= \sum_{l = 1}^{n}X_{l} \cdot 1_{\{T = l\}}
\end{align*}
and so in total for (\ref{eq3}) we get
\begin{align}\label{eq2}
\max_{1 \le k \le n}\left( X_{T \land k } \right) < K \cdot 1_{\{T \ge n + 1\}}   + \sum_{k = 1}^{n}X_{k} \cdot 1_{\{T = k\}} \, .
\end{align}
For each $k$ with $1\le k \le n$ we have
\begin{align}\label{eq4}
\{T = k\} \in \sigma\left( X_{1}, X_{2}, ... , X_{k}\right)
\end{align}
as $T$ is a stopping time. As $(X_{n})$ is a submartingal we have for every $k$ with $1\le k \le n$
\begin{align*}
 \mathbb{E} \left[  X_{n} |  \sigma \left( X_{1}, X_{2}, ... , X_{k} \right)\right] & \ge X_{k} \\
 \Leftrightarrow 1_{\{T = k\}} \cdot \mathbb{E} \left[  X_{n} |  \sigma \left( X_{1}, X_{2}, ... , X_{k} \right)\right] & \ge X_{k} \cdot 1_{\{T = k\}}
\end{align*}
and with (\ref{eq4}) we get
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E} \left[ 1_{\{T = k\}} \cdot X_{n} |  \sigma \left( X_{1}, X_{2}, ... , X_{k} \right)\right] & \ge X_{k} \cdot 1_{\{T = k\}} \, .
\end{align*}
By taking expectations on both sides we get
\begin{align}\label{eq1}
 \mathbb{E} \left[ X_{n} \cdot 1_{\{T = k\}} \right] \ge \mathbb{E} \left[ X_{k} \cdot 1_{\{T = k\}} \right] .
\end{align}
So in total  by taking expectations on both sides of  (\ref{eq2}) we have
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E} \left[ \max_{1 \le k \le n}\left( X_{T \land k } \right)\right] &< \mathbb{E} \left[ K  \cdot 1_{\{T \ge n+1 \}} \right] + \sum_{k = 1}^{n}  \mathbb{E} \left[  X_{k} \cdot 1_{\{T = k\}} \right] 
\end{align*}
and since $ \mathbb{E} \left[ K \cdot 1_{\{T \ge n+1\}} \right] = K \cdot \mathbb{E} \left[ 1_{\{T \ge n+1\}} \right] = K \cdot \mathbb{P} \left( T \ge n+1 \right)$ and with (\ref{eq1}) we have
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E} \left[ \max_{1 \le k \le n}\left( X_{T \land k } \right)\right]  &<  K  \cdot \mathbb{P} \left( T \ge n+1 \right) + \sum_{k = 1}^{n}  \mathbb{E} \left[  X_{n} \cdot 1_{\{T = k\}} \right] .
\end{align*}
Finally using 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}  \mathbb{E} \left[  X_{n} \cdot 1_{\{T = k\}} \right] =  \mathbb{E} \left[  \sum_{k = 1}^{n}  X_{n} \cdot 1_{\{T = k\}} \right] = \mathbb{E} \left[   X_{n} \cdot 1_{\{T \le k\}} \right]
\end{align*}
we get
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E} \left[ \max_{1 \le k \le n}\left( X_{T \land k } \right)\right]  &\le  K  \cdot \mathbb{P} \left( T \ge n+1 \right) + \mathbb{E} \left[   X_{n} \cdot 1_{\{T \le k\}} \right] 
\end{align*}
that results in
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E} \left[ \max_{1 \le k \le n}\left( X_{T \land k } \right)\right]  &\le  K   + \mathbb{E} \left[   X_{n}   \right] .
\end{align*}